# JS dataTable plugin: handling json format other than standard datatable format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am new to Datatables and trying to figure out this problem.
I have a server which oupts json in certain format(see below).I cant change that on server side.

****Note:** I am using link http://www.json-generator.com/j/cftupHnpbC?indent=4 to emulate my server response just for checking.

**I have 2 problems**

1. Since My json response doesn't have `aaData:` thing required by dataTable, I cant seem to initiliaze it.
2. Even if I add `aaData:`  by hand to json just for checking, dataTable cant count total records.How I can set that manually ?Since I cant change output from server.

**JSBIN LINK:**
http://live.datatables.net/dasuyaf/1/edit

**HTML:**

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').dataTable({
  "sAjaxSource": "http://www.json-generator.com/j/cftupHnpbC?indent=4",
    "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": "id",
      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="chkids[]" value="' + data + '">';
      }
    }, {
      "mData": "id"
    }, {
      "mData": "name"
    }, {
      "mData": "text"
    }], 
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sServerMethod": "GET",
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': [0]
    }],
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
      console.log(this.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal());
    }
  });
});
```

**My Server Output: (cant change this)**

```
[
    {
        "text": "Some text", 
        "name": "somedata", 
        "id": "89"
    }, 
    {
        "text": "Some text", 
        "name": "somedata", 
        "id": "2"
    }, 
    {
        "text": "Some text", 
        "name": "somedata", 
        "id": "12"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could just request that JSON yourself, make an object out of it and pass it to your dataTable.

```
var aaData;
var table;

$(document).ready( function () {
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/j/cftupHnpbC?indent=4'
}).done(function(data){
  aaData = data;
  table = $('#example').dataTable({
  "aaData": aaData,
    "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": "id",
      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="chkids[]" value="' + data + '">';
      }
    }, {
      "mData": "id"
    }, {
      "mData": "name"
    }, {
      "mData": "text"
    }], 
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': [0]
    }],
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
      console.log(this.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal());
    }
  });
  });  
} );
```

I removed `bServerSide` - I don't think there's any way you can make use of it if you can't change your server response. Also removed `sServerMethod`.